# how to pass the string without double quotes in rails string interpolation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string-interpolation

I am framing the query value like `'keys.description LIKE ?','desc%'` to pass inside where condition in active record query.

The problem is when I store this value in string

```
query = "'keys.description LIKE?','desc%'"
```

When I interpolate it in query `Class.select.where("#{query}")` the equivalent sql condition is coming like this `where('keys.description LIKE ?','desc%')` instead of `where(keys.description LIKE ? desc%)`.

Comment: Why are you storing it like `query="'keys.description LIKE?','desc%'")` in first place?

Comment: Actually i am filtering the table columns it will send equal to, not equal to,starts with,ends with,contains . so i have generic query which is big in that only where condition i will replace.

Comment: .where("value LIKE ?", "%#{value}%")

Comment: @ruby_newbie i know the syntax but when i interpolate string it comes like .where(""value LIKE ?", "%#{value}%"")

Comment: syntax and code formatting

Comment: You're trying to make a query like "WHERE keys.description LIKE 'desc%'", right? Why not just format this as an array like so: ["keys.description LIKE ?", "desc%"]